# symfony - key "id" for array with key "0,1,2,3,4,5,6" does not exist

Tags: javascript, symfony, leaflet

I have an error in my symfony project:

```
The key "id" for the array with the keys "0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6" does not exist.
```

I no longer have an object from 0 to 6 in my database because I had to overwrite the data with make: auth, I believe for security

I have new values but I don't know what to do to avoid this error.

I try to make the climbing sites of my database appear on my openstreet map. So I loop on the id in javascript, with the leaflet API.

```js
var sites = {
  "cul de l'elephant": {
    lat: 48.3727,
    lon: 2.51059,
  },
  Paris: {
    lat: 48.852969,
    lon: 2.349903,
  },
  Brest: {
    lat: 48.383,
    lon: -4.5,
  },
  Quimper: {
    lat: 48.0,
    lon: -4.1,
  },
  Bayonne: {
    lat: 43.5,
    lon: -1.467,
  },
};

var carte = L.map("macarte").setView([48.852969, 2.349903], 5);

L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/osmfr/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
  attribution:
    'données © <a href="//osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>/ODbL - rendu <a href="//openstreetmap.fr">OSM France</a>',
  minZoom: 1,
  maxZoom: 20,
}).addTo(carte);

var icone = L.icon({
  iconUrl: "../img/pointeur-de-carte.png",
  iconSize: [50, 50],
  iconAnchor: [25, 50],
  popupAnchor: [-2, -44],
});

for (site in sites) {
  var marqueur = L.marker([sites[site].lat, sites[site].lon], {
    icon: icone,
  }).addTo(carte);

  marqueur.bindPopup(
    <a href="{{ path('site_show', {'id':sites.id}) }}">site</a>
  );
}
```

I am getting the error quoted above.

here is the structure of my database
[image: here is the structure of my database]

Thank you. Cordially.

Comment: Shouldn't the popup link be `{'id':site.id}` instead of `{'id':sites.id}`?

Comment: I tryied and it says in this case "variable 'site' does not exist"

Comment: maybe you're rigth but I have to change something else...

Comment: I loaded a larger part of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation for `for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), when you use `sites.id` it isn't pointing to anything.

I am assuming that the data is not like you show, and you **do** have the ID value on the elements. If that is true, and your data looks like on the snippet, you have to update that reference to `sites[site].id`. Otherwise, edit your answer to show what your data looks like, with the ID on it.

```js
var sites = {
  "cul de l'elephant": {
    id: 12,
    lat: 48.3727,
    lon: 2.51059,
  },
  Paris: {
    id: 5,
    lat: 48.852969,
    lon: 2.349903,
  },
  Brest: {
    id: 34,
    lat: 48.383,
    lon: -4.5,
  },
  Quimper: {
    id: 75,
    lat: 48.0,
    lon: -4.1,
  },
  Bayonne: {
    id: 8,
    lat: 43.5,
    lon: -1.467,
  },
};

for (site in sites) {
  console.log(`Site "${site}" lat is ${sites[site].lat} and lng is ${sites[site].lon}`);
  // If your sites had an ID property, this is how you would access it
  console.log(`Site "${site}"'s ID is ${sites[site].id}`);  
}

console.log('####################');

// You could make the code easier to read updating the variable names
for (siteName in sites) {
  const site = sites[siteName];
  console.log(`Site ${siteName}: Id: ${site.id}, lat: ${site.lat}, lng: ${site.lon}`); 
}
```

It sounds like you control the server, an improvement could be to update the method to return an array of sites, instead of an object with site names as the keys, as follows:

```js
const sites = [
  {
    id: 12,
    name: "cul de l'elephant",
    lat: 48.3727,
    lon: 2.51059,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Paris',
    lat: 48.852969,
    lon: 2.349903,
  },
  {
    id: 34,
    name: 'Brest',
    lat: 48.383,
    lon: -4.5,
  },
  {
    id: 75,
    name: 'Quimper',
    lat: 48.0,
    lon: -4.1,
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: 'Bayonne',
    lat: 43.5,
    lon: -1.467,
  },
];
sites.forEach( site => {
  console.log(`Site ${site.name}: Id: ${site.id}, lat: ${site.lat}, lng: ${site.lon}`); 
});
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I just wanted to precise that with the dump of sites works,  my object, the arrayI with my data from the database. When I loop in js above with "site", I have the names of the sites from the script and not from the BDD displayed on the map in the popup. I cannot link site to the database. What I want is to make the link / path of the name of the site of the card to the site model, his personal file. 
You're rigth site is not a variable in twig, the dump of site says "variable site does not exist" , I can't go to the database totake the sites.

Comment: In fact my question is how to connect site or sitename from the map to the sites with ids and names, lon, lat .. of the the BDD

Comment: how make a link in the popup name to go the page of the site named in the popup, would be a better way to ask the question

Comment: I think the real question is how to write a link/path in a script whitch is in a twig in symfony. It would be simpler to try to anwer this way, isn't it?

Comment: I think that maybe the solution is to find a way to truncate the table so that we start again at ids 0. But I tryed and got this: 1701 - Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (pe4.media, CONSTRAINT FK_6A2CA10CF6BD1646 FOREIGN KEY (site_id) REFERENCES pe4.site (id)) . Could i do something like that ;SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

TRUNCATE table1;
TRUNCATE table2;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;?

Comment: What is preventing you from returning the data in the format I added at the bottom of the answer, an array of sites in a similar format to what you have in the database? Can you edit your question to show your database table structure?

Comment: I tryed with the arrays you gave me without changing the other parts of the code but it gave me the same error. Then I put new sites inside your arrays with numbers 0 to 6, but I still have the same error that I had at the begining for the ids witch does not exist.

Comment: Where do you get the `The key "id" for the array with the keys "0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6" does not exist.` error? Do you have anywhere we can look at bigger parts of your code? It looks like the code throwing the error is not available in the question.

Comment: hi, the error happends when i try to load the page index.html.twig and this is precisely when I try to link the popup with the <a href . Initialy I wrote      //marqueur.bindPopup(site);  whitch shows the popup from the marker on the map. When I try to make the link a href="{{ path('site_show', {'id':sites.id}) }}">site</a> inside it gives me the error. I think as site is an entity , it goes looking for the ids of all the sites in the entity site. And there is missing the 7th first. Can we make the path/link without touching the ids?

Comment: I find that I had to ask directly the DB and I tryed with var site = {{sites.id}} in the script and then make the loop. But I got another error  whitch is Key "id" for array with keys "0, 1, 2" does not exist.